# Touch ID not working after dropping iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, touch-id

Today when I was playing with my friends, my iPhone 5s fell down. After that, it didn't work for a couple of minutes and then it worked but the Touch ID stopped working completely. When I went to Settings, I was not able to click the Add Fingerprint option. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that your TouchID sensor incurred some hardware damage.

I recommend that you contact your local Apple retailer.